# How to change the width of google sign in button (js/css)?

Tags: javascript, css, authentication, oauth, openid

And also, **can** I do it? I'm not sure about those legal things, I hope I won't be sued for changing its width and height a little bit.
As you can see in the attached picture, I've changed the size of "Sign in with Apple", but how do I do it with the Google's button?

I initialize this button via js like this:

```
window.google.accounts.id.initialize({
  client_id: "client_id",
});
window.google.accounts.id.renderButton(
  googleSignIn.current,
  {
    theme: "outline",
    size: "large",
    type: "standard",
  }
);
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try [data-width](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/personalized-button)?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in other answers you can change the width in the render button method. If you wish to change the height the only way I've found is to do a css transform on the target element to scale it to the size you need. With small adjustments it can look pretty good.

```
window.google.accounts.id.renderButton(
  document.getElementById('googleAuth'),
  { theme: 'outline', size: 'large', width: 309, text: 'continue_with' }
);
```

Then in your css section

```
#googleAuth {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

Comment: thnks i think this is the only hack that would work!

Answer (score 0):

You can set width from range 240px - 400px

`window.google.accounts.id.renderButton( googleSignIn.current, { theme: "outline", size: "large", type: "standard", width: "your width value in px"  } );`